# Why is a reliced guitar often more expensive than a corresponding normal model?

Tags: electric-guitar

Guitar makers like Fender or Gibson offers a reliced model of a guitar, and set the price higher than the original one. I'm not referring to "Collector Edition" or "Artist Series", but a guitar like the Fender Stratocaster Standard being reliced and this makes the price higher than the normal one.

**What makes it more expensive? Isn't it made with the same specification?**

PS: Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer contains some speculation, but the relicing process actually involves some work, and possibly they are charging for that. People might also be prepared to pay more for a factory worn guitar (which is quite strange).

Usually, as you have noticed, the reliced instruments are in the higher end, custom shop made range. The manufacturers might want to use this to push up the prices on normal range reliced instruments too. People have their mind set on a custom shop, but realize that they can't afford it, and then they might accept a higher priced normal guitar.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about supply and demand. This is no different than a blue jean company charging more for a pair of worn out faded jeans than they charge for a regular pair, just because they can. 
 This case has another twist. Many people don't want to look like a newbie with a shiny new guitar. It is very chic to be able to look like your guitar shows years of dedicated playing.

Also, take into consideration that the relicing is another step of construction that someone needs to get paid to do. These are not monkeys with sledgehammers. These are people carefully scratching paint and whatnot to approximate years of use. That means realizing where these instruments usually wear out and to what degree.